# RedirectMatch not working in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Iam trying to to redirect my page from

> from http://domain.com/article.php?id=23232
>   to http://domain.com/article/23232

am using this syntax in .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 article.php?id=(.*)$ http://domain/article/$1
```

so please what is the error in this?

Answer (score 1):

You cant match query string using `RedirectMatch`. Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ http://domain.com/article/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank sir, but this is just redirecting to http://domain.com/article without taking the id

Comment: Sorry there was typo mistake, corrected it now. Please try again.